# The argument type 'Pattern' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'?

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication

I'm just starting out with authentication and have this error.

```
validator: (value) {
                          Pattern pattern =
                              r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)| (\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
                          RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
                          if (!regex.hasMatch(value!))
                            return 'Enter a valid email';
                          else
                            return null;
                        },
```

Copied from here: https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-implement-autofill-in-your-flutter-app-b43bddab1a97

But fixed one error, had to add null check to `(value!))`. Is this a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the reference, Check the below code

```
validator: (value) {
if (value != null || value.isNotEmpty) {
final RegExp regex =
  RegExp(r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)| (\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$');
  if (!regex.hasMatch(value!))
      return 'Enter a valid email';
  else
      return null;
} else {
  return 'Enter a valid email';
}},
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick